# Windows + Docker + Port not exposed/reachable

Tags: windows, docker, port

**Problem:**

From the windows host machine. Port mapping/exposing does not work.

Container app is not reachable.

```
curl http://localhost:PORT (127.0.0.1 / 0.0.0.0)
-> Could not get any response

curl http://DOCKER-IP:PORT (127.17.0.1 / 127.17.0.2)
-> Could not get any response

curl http://DOCKER-SUBNET-ADDRESS:PORT (10.0.75.0)
-> Could not get any response
```

**Setup:**

Windows10 host system 
+ 
Docker container (with simple helloworld python flask app)

Docker container is running.
Inside the docker container the flask app behaves as expected.

**Reproduction:**

1. get the hello world repo

   `git clone https://github.com/shekhargulati/python-flask-docker-hello-world`
2. Build and run docker container

   `docker build -t simple-flask-app:latest .
   docker run -d -p 5000:5000 simple-flask-app --name simple-flask-app`
3. exec into container & check flask is running

   `docker exec -it simple-flask-app
   apt-get install curl
   curl http://127.0.0.1:5000`

   -> See `200 OK + Flask is running` (or some text like this)
4. Exit docker container

   `exit`
5. curl on your windows host machine

   `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000`

   -> See `Could not get any response` (or something like this)

Answer (score 17):

You need to set the app to run on host='0.0.0.0'. That is:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

So when you run:

```
> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 simple-flask-app --name simple-flask-app
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
```

Then `curl http://localhost:5000` works.

Credit goes to:
https://codefresh.io/docker-tutorial/hello-whale-getting-started-docker-flask/

Comment: This! After countless searches and attempts to fix, reinstall, routing changes, trying with direct IP... This was the solution, and no one is mentioning it anywhere...

Comment: Finally! In my case it was starting my app in docker container with
vue-cli-service serve --host 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 9):

I just changed the order of the name parameter and it worked (in Linux).

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name simple-flask-app simple-flask-app
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I had the -p xxxx:xxxx at the end.

Comment: ARGH why the @#$@# does this make a difference!

Comment: It makes a difference because the container name separates docker arguments from container arguments; everything before the container name are docker arguments, everything after the container name are container arguments.

Answer (score 9):

For me, the simplest solution was to run:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

This prints an IP address. In my case, this IP is not shown by ipconfig.
I tested with Docker 18.03.0-ce on a Windows 7 Host.

I found this tip here: https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/020_tip_using_docker_containers_as_localhost_on_mac_and_windows.html

Comment: Yep, run `docker-machine ip` then use provided ip instead of a localhost:
`http://<docker-machine ip>:<exposed port>`

Answer (score 2):

**Short Solution**

1. Run your docker app
   1.1 (Exec into your docker and make sure your app is working as expected)
2. On your windows host

   ipconfig
3. One of those exposed IPv4 addresses will work. Just try all one by one.

   `curl http://IPCONFIG-IPv4-TRY-OUT:PORT
   -> 200 OK + Flask is running`

-> Docker on windows does not forward traffic to the docker container as known from linux/mac.

-> It looks like traffic is forwared to eth0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the VM where docker is actually running:

Find the ip address by running `docker-machine ip default` and use that ip to connect:

```
curl http://<ip-address>:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to flask but I had the same problem recently. Our host machine needed a static IP address so some network configuration was changed by our IT. I then noticed the vEthernet adapter in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections was disabled. After enabling this port forwarding to the container instance seemed to work again.